# Вывести в консоль значения тегов с классами

Tags: jquery

Помогите нубу =) как в консоль вывести значения данных дивов с классами?

```
 <div class='test'>Значение 1</div>
 <div class='test'>Значение 2</div>

<script>
var value=$('.test');
console.log(num[0].text());
console.log(num[1].text());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>Значение 1</div>
 <div class='test'>Значение 2</div>

<script>
var value=$('.test');
console.log($(value[0]).text()); // console.log(value[0].textContent);
console.log($(value[1]).text()); // console.log(value[1].textContent);
</script>
```

Comment: Благодарствую, други.... протупил в названиях переменных! Добра вам=)

Comment: а как же там `console.log($(".test").map(el => $(el).text()).get())` ?

Comment: @teran зачем?..

Comment: так может у него там 50 дивов таких ) так и напишет отдельными строками ) зы: просто дополнил в комменте, мб пригодится тс

Comment: @teran в условии ничего нет, а за автора придумывать доп. условия не вижу смысла ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  да и уровень у него очевидно новичковый и ему пока не до всех этих конструкций. Он просто познаёт мир